# Windows 7 TCP strange ACK behaviour?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, windows-7

I have machine with Windows 7.
My MTU is 1300 because I use VPN software (not relevant to my question) so my MSS is 1260. my IP is 10.0.0.87.

Wireshark capture:
https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/cef30c54b1b8

I'm making HTTP GET request to receive some web page.
Let's start at segment no 8. My system sends ACK to 2 previous packets.
On segment no. 13 my system sends ACK to 4 previous packets.
segment no 18 ACK to 4 previous packets.
segment no 30 ACK to 11 previous packets.

I know about delayed ACK and so on, but why Windows7 sends ACK in that manner?
Is there any documentation about that?
Using Delayed ACK strictly, my machine should send ACK after 2 unacked segments (or after 500ms when no data is in flight)

Anyone knows what is this scheme of sending ACK in that manner?

Comment: Google "tcp window size".

Comment: I'm not exceding tcp window size, that has hothing to do with ACK. Check wireshark dump

Answer (score 1):

You're right. It is strange. I'm not sure why the downvotes other than people don't understand what you're asking. You're also right that TCP should ACK every other segment or after the delayed-ack timer expires for a single segment.

I think this is likely related to offloading and the NIC handling the data processing and ACK sending instead of the Windows TCP stack. Try disabling TCP Chimney to see if the behavior changes:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037

If it does, then you can research offloading for your NIC driver.

If it doesn't, try disabling autotuning as a next step to narrow it down:

http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=247